# It is possible to incorporate in the Tags main page the additional filter "Watchers"?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-management, design, tag-watching

I would like to make a suggestion for the Tag main page, were currently they could be found the filters by: Popular/Name/New

In my short experience here so far, I have been really useful to know also the amount of "Watchers" of each tag, so I am asking to add also this filter to order the tags by the number of Watchers each of them have, when looking for them in the Tag main page.

Sometimes the best suitable tags have almost no watchers and only a few questions, so after making a list of the suitable task of a question, ranking them by the number of Watchers, and picking the top 5, have help me to find better answers in a faster way.

I believe is not something too hard to implement.

Hope this also make sense to you,

Beforehand, thanks you very much for your time.

Comment: A _very_ old feature request on [metase] making the same suggestion: [Sort tags by number of followers (add a tab to the tag page)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81395).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist thanks for commenting. I saw the link you share an upvote it. But I don't really know how to use that information in other way.... What you were expecting me to do with that?

Comment: I posted the link just for general information :) In any case, I have upvoted your feature request since I think it would be an improvement to the Tags page.

Comment: Please don't change the tags to game the system. Place the tags that are most accurate to describing the subject of the question - and if you don't get an answer, be patient, or make more effort to solve yourself.

Comment: @Nij why not? Once a day is not against the site policies, and do it improves my probabilities of finding answers. PS: If you believe that because you do effort you will always solve everythin by yourself, you be will always limiting yourself to learn better ways from others

Comment: Because that's not what tags are for, nor is it what questions are for. Tags make finding questions relevant to a topic easier - so that askers and answerers can both find them. Questions here should be more relevant than just one person's needs - that's what "repository of high-quality Q&A" means. If you want a tutor now, there are other sites available for that.

Comment: [@Nij](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34872/it-is-possible-to-incorporate-in-the-tags-main-page-the-additional-filter-watch?noredirect=1#comment163229_34872) is right. Cycling through popular tags solely to draw attention to your question is inappropriate. It would also be better if you rollback to the original revision of this feature request.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I will follow your indication. But I am totally disagree with the background of the solicitation: your actually asking people that is supposedly to be smart to act like otherwise.

Comment: @Nij Is exactly the opposite. If a take the time to redact a good and interesting question, and I choose a tag that nobody is viewing, is a lost of time for me, and also a lost in knowledge, since it could be interesting for people that could answer it, and also other that could have the same doubt and can use the information. Your "tutor" argument is a really poor one, and doing so it will only lead to a site full of unanswered question, which is nonsense.

Comment: [@Joako](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34872/it-is-possible-to-incorporate-in-the-tags-main-page-the-additional-filter-watch?noredirect=1#comment163241_34872) Perhaps you felt it was implicit that you would only add tags that are appropriate to the question, and among those you would choose the "popular" ones? If so, then there is no disagreement. I think the current version of your post is clear, but the previous version was a bit ambiguous.